# sqoop query to get sql server data into cloudera manager

Tags: cloudera, sqoop, impala

sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://IP address;username=user;password=pswd;database=Master' --table [Person].[BusinessEntityContact] --target-dir /home/ubuntu/hdfs/dir  is not working .

Reference:http://mapredit.blogspot.com/2011/10/sqoop-and-microsoft-sql-server.html   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5mBB.png

Answer (score 0):

In your error logs got SQLServerException and says "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties.". Please check whether you have access from where you try run this command and also MSSQL port "1433". Then add number of maps "-m" in your command.

Comment: Request clarification or suggest improvements.

Comment: Thanks for responding Vasanth .I am getting the listed error:  " Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 131.107.174.121, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."  I would like to know how I can establish a connection with SQL server and Cloudera using Ubuntu from AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Nirmale
can you try from your unix box to

```
curl http://131.107.174.121:1433
```

If you get "Empty reply from server" it is ok, or if you get an error like "couldn't connect to host", check with your SQL Server admin as to what port the SQL Server is listening on.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check is using sqoop list-tables command, something as follows:
sqoop list-tables -connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://IP address;username=user;password=pswd;database=Master' -username  --password